# Video not running in the webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I am running the video (vimeo video player) using the webview. But when i click on the start button then nothing happen. Please help me is there any alternative so that it start to work.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

String web = "<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + 75195844 + "\"" + " width=\"800\" height=\"800\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";


mWebView.loadData(web, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use loadDataWithBaseURL instead of loadData.

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><body>" + web + "</body></html>", null, "UTF-8", null);
```